# JAXB Problem w. Java 11: ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.ContextFactory after jlink

Tags: maven, jaxb, java-11, java-module

I have a modular Java / JavaFX, both Version 19 project in Eclipse. I use Maven to build the project. This project uses JAXB. The project runs fine within Eclipse if I use "clean javafx:run" as goal. In order to share the app, I wanted to create a runnable jar. In order to do that I used clean "javafx:jlink" as goal. This runs successful - well, to some extend. If I start the application on the Jlink image, the application starts, but it can't read the related user date since JAXB fails:

```
    jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of Jakarta XML Binding-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.ContextFactory]
        at jakarta.xml.bind@4.0.0/jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:252)
        at jakarta.xml.bind@4.0.0/jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:240)
        at jakarta.xml.bind@4.0.0/jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:381)
        at jakarta.xml.bind@4.0.0/jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:605)
        at jakarta.xml.bind@4.0.0/jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:546)
        at sifuSays@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/de.levin.persistance.Persistance.loadSessions(Persistance.java:49)
        at sifuSays@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/de.levin.ctrl.MainCtrl.initialize(MainCtrl.java:1005)
        at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2655)
        at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
        at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2516)
        at sifuSays@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/de.levin.sifuSays.App.start(App.java:125)
        at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
        at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
        at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
        at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
        at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.ContextFactory
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at jakarta.xml.bind@4.0.0/jakarta.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.nullSafeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:113)
        at jakarta.xml.bind@4.0.0/jakarta.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.safeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:146)
        at jakarta.xml.bind@4.0.0/jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:250)
        ... 19 more
```

Many of the "solutions" that I found are several years old and refer to version 2.3.1. When I tried to use these old version, I can't fulfill the requirements regarding modules - at least I don't know how to fix that the module-info.java can resolve the error.
Anyway, in addition to

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I tried two different implementations in my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

And, as recommended by [Jakarta XML Binding](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jaxb-ri/)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>old version.
```

The creation of the Jlink image is based on

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                    <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>sifuSays/de.levin.sifuSays.App</mainClass>
                        <launcher>launchSifuSays</launcher>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
```

always the same error message. I played around with several version combinations, but what strikes me, is that the error message always refers to v2. To trigger the build I use "clean javafx:jlink", so actually any old / wrong version should disappear from the build.

Any idea how to fix this?
What would be interesting is why it works from within the Eclipse IDE?
Maybe I need to reimplement the functionality with a different Java XML strategy?! If there is no reasonable way to fix the current setup, which XML approach is Java 11 using  module architecture compliant?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I would change

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.3</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>old version.
```

To:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.4</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

I was running into the same error. I updated the version on the impl to 4.0.4 and the issue went away. The other thing I would do is remove the word old version. I'm not sure but I think it could mess things up.